# How to inject session key in raw chain specs?

Tags: chainspec

Is is possible to add/delete session keys directly to the raw chain specs instead of plain chain specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. That's possible.

For example:

[QueuedKeys](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/915d22ccaa45b2b93b1eb4194b4349c1db7930d8/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L520)

```rs
/// The queued keys for the next session. When the next session begins, these keys
/// will be used to determine the validator's session keys.
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn queued_keys)]
pub type QueuedKeys<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, Vec<(T::ValidatorId, T::Keys)>, ValueQuery>;
```

`T::ValidatorId` is the `AccountId` which you configured in the runtime. `T::Keys` is the `SessionKeys` which you configured in the runtime.

- [`AccountId`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/915d22ccaa45b2b93b1eb4194b4349c1db7930d8/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L228)
- [`SessionKeys`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/915d22ccaa45b2b93b1eb4194b4349c1db7930d8/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L513-L520)

```rs
let validator_id = H256::default();
let session_keys = SessionKeys { ..Default::default() };
let queued_keys = vec![(validator_id, session_keys)].encode();
let hex = array_bytes::bytes2hex("0x", queued_keys);

println!("{hex}");
```

Use Subalfred, PolkadotJS or any other tools to get the storage key.

```sh
λ subalfred storage-key --pallet Session --item QueuedKeys
0xcec5070d609dd3497f72bde07fc96ba0e0cdd062e6eaf24295ad4ccfc41d4609
```

Open the raw JSON file, and search `0xcec5070d609dd3497f72bde07fc96ba0e0cdd062e6eaf24295ad4ccfc41d4609`. Change its value to `println!("{hex}");`'s output.

And you need to do this for the other necessary storage as well.